# How to find a GameObjects Prefab during runtime with Unity version 2018.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After updating to Unity 2018.3.0f2 I`m unable to find a GameObjects prefab while the game is running. In the previous versions i was simply using this line:

```
GameObject prefabObject = 
    PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource(gameObject);
```

But after the update this function only returns null, so I tried the new functions:

1. PrefabUtility.GetPrefabInstanceHandle
2. PrefabUtility.GetNearestPrefabInstanceRoot
3. PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot

but all of them return null but I`m sure that I am handing a prefab over as parameter. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: PrefabUtility is in the `UnityEditor` namespace, so it only works in the editor. This has never been otherwise as far as I know.

Comment: @Draco18s Yeah i know, but I only need my script when I start the game in the editor.

Comment: `but I'm sure that I am handing a prefab over as parameter` .. shouldn't you rather pass a reference of an instance of a prefab from your scene instead of a prefab itself? Also I'm not sure if this works on runtime (/in play mode) .. never tried it but I don't know if changing a prefab on runtime would also change the instances ... Meaning I'm not sure if instances are still linked to prefabs at runtime (/in play mode) at all

Comment: @derHugo i dont want to change the prefab i rather want to get the asset path and it worked before the update :/ and yeah, im handing over a reference of an instance, i just described that poorly

Comment: maybe you could check [IsPartOfAnyPrefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.IsPartOfAnyPrefab.html) and [GetPrefabInstanceStatus](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetPrefabInstanceStatus.html) just to be sure the link to the prefab is intact in the moment your code is executed.

Comment: @derHugo it seems indeed like the links from prefabs disapear when the play mode is entered. this is quite unfortunate for me, but thanks anyway

Comment: I am having this same problem with 2018. IsPartOfAnyPrefab always returns false (I'm running code in OnValidate, game NOT running, OnValidate triggered by editing a component in a prefab.) GetPrefabInstanceStatus always returns "NotAPrefab", again, even though I'm clearly inside a prefab with the game not running.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as editor start playing (Application.isPlaying=true) prefab linkage with scene game objects will be broken (blue game objects turned into gray) and thus you cannot obtain prefab related information from it.

If you really need a scenario were you want to access such information on runtime, you should save it as Serialized variable in script component so that it will later available on runtime.

**For example**: this is a simplified contraption of what Mirror (Unity network plugin) is doing by issuing asset ID related stuff to help distinguish each prefab to spawn things in network on runtime.

```
    [SerializeField] string m_AssetId;

    void OnValidate() // Which will be called on build or editor play
    {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
         // Deposit UnityEditor API dependent into some field
         m_AssetId = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath( gameObject );
    #endif
    }
```

---

Anyway, for running **editor script**, if you want to test or look for original prefab. **UnityEditor.PrefabUtility** is somewhat hard to find a full example of how to use them.

You can refer to my git repository on how to use them with examples.

https://github.com/wappenull/UnityPrefabTester

[image]